# How to change the class of elements that have matching content

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have:

```
<div class="bar">baz</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
<div class="foo">baz</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
<div class="foo">baz</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
```

And I would like all the elements that contain the same content as the one with a class of "bar" to also have a class of "bar" like so:

```
<div class="bar">baz</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
<div class="bar">baz</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
<div class="bar">baz</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
```

But I can't just search for "baz" because that content is subject to change. Instead I have to figure out what's in the lone "bar" div then find the others that match it and change their class to "bar" too.

I've managed to get the content of the first "bar" element into a variable:

```
var = body.css(".bar").first.inner_text
```

But nothing I've tried from there as far as finding the matching content and replacing the class has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful using `body.css("div:contains('#{text_to_match}')")`.

```
input = '<div class="bar">baz</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
<div class="foo">baza</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
<div class="foo">bazfdsfsdf</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>'
```

The output will be:

```
<div class="bar">baz</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
<div class="bar">baza</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
<div class="bar">bazfdsfsdf</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
```

If you want to match the exact same text in both elements, you should use:
`body.css("div[text() = '#{text_to_match}']")`

```
input = '<div class="bar">baz</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
<div class="foo">baza</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
<div class="foo">bazfdsfsdf</div>
<div class="foo">baz</div>'
```

The output would be:

```
<div class="bar">baz</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
<div class="foo">baza</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
<div class="foo">bazfdsfsdf</div>
<div class="bar">baz</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `body.css('div:contains("<text-to-match>")')` to match the nodes containing the text content you want.

You can achieve what you want by doing something like:

```
require 'nokogiri'

input = '<div class="bar">baz</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
<div class="foo">baz</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
<div class="foo">baz</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>'

body = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(input)

text_to_match = body.at_css('.bar').text

matching_nodes = body.css("div:contains('#{text_to_match}')")
matching_nodes.each do |node|
  node['class'] = 'bar'
end

puts body.to_html
```

Comment: Cool thanks this works! Only problem now is its also targeting the divs that contain the divs that contain baz. Have to figure out how to just target the divs that directly contain baz not their parents.

Comment: "Have to figure out how to just target the divs that directly contain baz not their parents" So your example and question are not what they should be? Don't ask questions that creep; Figure out what the real question is first then ask. Failing to do so wastes everyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div class="bar">baz</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
<div class="foo">baz</div>
EOT

target_text = doc.at('.bar').text # => "baz"
doc.search("//div[text()='#{target_text}']").each do |div|
  div['class'] = 'bar'
end
```

Which results in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<div class="bar">baz</div>
<div class="foo">qux</div>
<div class="bar">baz</div>
</body></html>
```

There's nothing that says we can't mix CSS and XPath selectors. XPath has more capabilities, but it is visually noisy, so I use CSS when I can and XPath when I have to.

XPath makes it easy to search all nodes for text, so it's a good choice for that task.